# Wikipedia Extractor - Get rid of title in text

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I used the [WikiExtractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor) to extract the XML dump into JSON files for further pre-processing of the data. My Problem is that the title is always part of the text.

Here is an example:

```
"Alan Smithee\n\nAlan Smithee steht als Pseudonym (...)"
"Actinium\n\nActinium ist ein radioaktives chemisches Element (...)"
"Aussagenlogik\n\nDie Aussagenlogik ist ein Teilgebiet der (...)"
```

How do I get rid of the title in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your texts at `'\n\n'` once and take the last part:

```
texts = ["Alan Smithee\n\nAlan Smithee steht als Pseudonym (...)",
        "Actinium\n\nActinium ist ein radioaktives chemisches Element (...)",
        "Aussagenlogik\n\nDie Aussagenlogik ist ein Teilgebiet der (...)",
        "No split text here" ]

# split once and take the last part of it as result into your cleaned list
cleaned = [i.split("\n\n", 1)[-1] for i in texts]

print(cleaned)
```

Output:

```
['Alan Smithee steht als Pseudonym (...)', 
 'Actinium ist ein radioaktives chemisches Element (...)', 
 'Die Aussagenlogik ist ein Teilgebiet der (...)', 
 'No split text here']
```

See  [str.**split**(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) - provide *maxsplit* of 1 to only split once and take all the remainder as result.